# Why do I keep getting the exception - "The servlet or filters that are being used by this request do not support async operation"?

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous

My application keeps throwing the exception - `The servlet or filters that are being used by this request do not support async operation` even though I have added the `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` to all the filters and servlet in web.xml

Here is how my servlet looks like:

`@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/MyServlet"}, asyncSupported=true)`

and the below piece of code is throwing the exception repeatedly:

`final AsyncContext asyncContext = request.startAsync(request, response);`

Are there other changes that I have missed out which is resulting in the application throwing this exception repeatedly?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Give us a little code.

Comment: Updated. See if it helps in suggesting.